# Swift2 error: 'UISearchController' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer, despite deployment target 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I just converted an older swift project to Swift 2, and I'm getting errors like:

'UISearchController' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer

The strange thing ist, the deployment target of the project is 8.1. Why does the compiler ignores this? I do not want to scatter the code with "if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { ... }".

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check to see if a value for the app target's Deployment Info overrode the project's Deployment Info?

Comment: That was it, thanks Petah!